# How to filter out values from an array within an indexed list of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an indexed list of products, and each product has a price, as well as an array of bulk prices. I want to filter out all bulk prices that are higher than the product's base price. What's the best way to do this with ES6 features like destructuring.

Here is the list of prices:

```
prices: {
  foo: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 150, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  },
  bar: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 180, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  }
 }
```

You can see that the first bulk price for the second product is higher than the base price so it should be removed. So the result should be:

```
prices: {
  foo: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 150, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  },
  bar: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  }
 }
```

I can do it like this:

```
Object.entries(prices).map(([sku, product])=> { 
       return { 
         [sku]: { 
           ...product, 
           bulkPricing: product.bulkPricing.filter(bp => bp.price < product.price)
         }
       }
     }
     )
```

But this of course returns an array:

```
[ { foo: { price: 160, bulkPricing: [{price: 150, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}] } },
  { bar: { price: 160, bulkPricing: [{price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}] } } ]
```

So I guess my question is, with the latest ES6 techniques how can I filter items in an object based on arrays within those items, and return that modified object?

Comment: Do you *need* a new object, or is modifying the old one OK?

Comment: It is being used inside a React reducer... creating a new object might be preferable? Not 100% sure

Comment: Thanks, note that your `prices` keys (`001`), since they're numeric, will be parsed as just `1` (etc) by the interpreter. If you need the leading zeros, use a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Another option:

ES6 & Destructuring:

```
Object.keys(prices).reduce((obj, key) => ({
    ...obj,
    [key]: {
        ...prices[key],
        bulkPricing: prices[key].bulkPricing
            .filter(({ price }) => price <= prices[key].price)
    }
}), {});
```

***Note**: it does not use `Object.values` as it's not yet widely supported in older browsers and it does not mutate the prices object.*

Comment: That’s the same solution I came up with in the end but I used Object.Entries

Comment: @grabury unlike `Array.map` that returns an array, I demonstrate the same solution as you but used reduce, which allows you to control the result type (and answer your requirement which is to return an object). I don't see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. It was a compliment.

Comment: @grabury my apologies! We our solution is similar except how we manipulate the object. +1

Comment: To clarify: After I posted the question I came up with a similar solution that used reduce and object.entries

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `forEach` along with the function `filter` to get only those objects with the `price` equal to or lesser than the specific `price`.

```js
let obj = {  prices: {    foo: {      price: 160,      bulkPricing: [{          price: 150,          minimumQuantity: 10        },        {          price: 140,          minimumQuantity: 20        },        {          price: 130,          minimumQuantity: 30        }      ]    },    bar: {      price: 160,      bulkPricing: [{          price: 180,          minimumQuantity: 10        },        {          price: 140,          minimumQuantity: 20        },        {          price: 130,          minimumQuantity: 30        }      ]    }  }};

Object.values(obj.prices).forEach(p => p.bulkPricing = p.bulkPricing.filter(b => b.price <= p.price));

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `filter` the `bulkPricing` array, creating a copy first to avoid mutation of the original object:

```js
const prices = {
  001: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 150, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  },
  002: {
   price: 160,
   bulkPricing: [
    {price: 180, minimumQuantity: 10},
    {price: 140, minimumQuantity: 20},
    {price: 130, minimumQuantity: 30}
   ]
  }
};
const newPrices = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prices));
Object.values(newPrices).forEach((item) => {
  const { price: basePrice, bulkPricing } = item;
  item.bulkPricing = item.bulkPricing.filter(({ price }) => price < basePrice);
});
console.log(newPrices);
```